# How can I order this struct using qsort()?

Tags: c

I have these structs,

```
 typedef struct
{
  int votos; //Votes
  float classifica; //Rating
  char* titulo; //Title
  int ano;     //Year
} vg_elemento;

/**
* this register has a vetorg of elements a counter for the size and a counter for the capacity  
*/
typedef struct
{
  /** numero de elementos do vetorg */
  int tamanho;       //size

  /** capacidade do vetorg */
  int capacidade; //capacity

  /** array of stored elements */
  vg_elemento* elementos;

} vetorg;
```

I heard that there is a qsort() function that allows me to sort an array, I tried checking the internet but all examples either use int, float or strings. How can I use the qsort() function using the structures above?

I have some comparing functions, already given:

```
 typedef int (*comp)(const vg_elemento a, const vg_elemento b);

int comp_ano_asc(const vg_elemento a, const vg_elemento b){ //sorts bt year
    if(b.ano > a.ano)
        return -1;
    if(a.ano > b.ano)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int comp_votos_asc(const vg_elemento a, const vg_elemento b) //sorts by votes
{
    if(b.votos > a.votos)
        return -1;
    if(a.votos > b.votos)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int comp_classifica_asc(const vg_elemento a, const vg_elemento b) //sorts by rating
{
    if(b.classifica > a.classifica)
        return -1;
    if(a.classifica > b.classifica)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int comp_titulo_asc(const vg_elemento a, const vg_elemento b) //sorts by title (alphabetically)
{
    if(strcmp(b.titulo,a.titulo)>0)
        return -1;
    if(strcmp(a.titulo,b.titulo)>0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to sort the array using a function, calling qsort() in that function. Eg:

```
    int vetorg_ordena(vetorg* vec, comp ordem){

    //sorts the array according to ordem in an ascending order. returns 0, if successful
}
```

Here's an example of a sample array of size 3:

```
Votes Rating Year Title
319656 8.8 2010 Inception
511125 8.8 2008 The Dark Knight
227431 8.3 1983 Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this `qsort` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) you will see that the comparison function gets passed *pointers*. The pointers it gets passes are pointers to elements in the array being sorted.

So if you have an array of `vg_elemento` like

```
vg_elemento videos[SOME_SIZE];
```

Then the comparison function is basically called like

```
comp(&videos[i], &videos[j]);
```

That in turns means your functions should look like

```
int comp_ano_asc(const void *a, const void *b){ //sorts bt year
    const vg_elemento *va = (vg_elemento *) a;
    const vg_elemento *vb = (vg_elemento *) b;

    if(vb->ano > va->ano)
        return -1;
    if(ba->ano > vb->ano)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poetic - very nice (aside from I'd use `if(va->ano < vb->ano)
        return -1;` to show _less than_.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot for the answer.