# How to write qsort() comparator for sentence and text structs?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, qsort, wchar-t

Suppose I have a `struct Sentence` and a `struct Text`. How do I implement qsort on `capital_letters_quant`? How can you write out the same compare function?

```
struct Sentence {
    wchar_t* sentence_text;
    size_t sentence_size;   
    bool is_sentence_anagram;
    int64_t capital_letters_quant;
};

struct Text {
    struct Sentence* full_text;
    size_t full_text_size;
};
```

So, I tried to change the arguments of the compare function to struct Sentence *, but the compiler gave warnings or errors, I would not want to receive them, to be honest...

This is my atmpt to do it

```
int second_compare(const void* first_current_sentence, const void* second_current_sentence) {
    return ((struct Sentence*)second_current_sentence -> capital_letters_quant) - ((struct Sentence*)first_current_sentence -> capital_letters_quant);
}
```

But gcc send me this

error: conflicting types for 'second_compare'; have 'int(const void *, const void *)'

note: previous declaration of 'second_compare' with type 'int(struct Sentence *, struct Sentence *)'

warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer

error: request for member 'capital_letters_quant' in something not a structure or union

error: request for member 'capital_letters_quant' in something not a structure or union

Comment: So, I tried to change the arguments of the compare function to struct Sentence *, but the compiler gave warnings or errors, I would not want to receive them, to be honest...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose. Show your attempts to implement a comparison function and copy&paste the error messages. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43100263/10622916

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: K, it seems that I did everything, as I was told, did I formulate the question correctly?

Comment: Hey, Bodo, how can I make your answer correct? It really help me, thanks!

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code... that's obvious from errors

Comment: Make a complete code example that we can copy a run

Comment: I complete this task, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

- First, you should change your declaration of `second_compare` to `int second_compare (const void *, const void *);` because the types of arguments in declaration and in definition must be the same.
- Second, the `->` operator has greater priority relatively to cast operator `(struct Sentence *)`, which means that compiler first tries to access field `capital_letters_quant` in the structure pointed to by the void pointer, thus it tries to dereference it. To fix this, you should first cast, then dereference: `... ((struct Sentence *) data) -> field ...`.
- Third, your function takes two pointers, referencing constant values (as far as you marked them with `const`). But in the body of function you cast these values to non-constant values of type `(struct Sentence *)`, whilst you should cast to constant values of type `(const struct Sentence *)`.